# ¿Cómo hago para que el siguiente número cambie de color sólo cuando está en la posición de escritura de código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

El proyecto es un editor de código html5 que permite ejecutar el código pulsando un botón y borrarlo pulsando otro botón.

```js
const editorContent = document.getElementById('editor-content');
const lineNumbers = document.getElementById('line-numbers');
const htmlCode = document.getElementById('html-code');
const previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');

document.getElementById('run-btn').addEventListener('click', updatePreview);
document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', resetPreview);
htmlCode.addEventListener('input', updateLineNumbers);
editorContent.addEventListener('scroll', syncScroll);

function updatePreview() {
  let html = htmlCode.value;
  previewFrame.srcdoc = html;
}

function resetPreview() {
  htmlCode.value = '';
  previewFrame.srcdoc = '';
  updateLineNumbers(); // Resetear también la numeración
}

function updateLineNumbers() {
  const lines = htmlCode.value.split('\n').length;
  const lineNumbersContent = Array.from({ length: lines }, (_, index) => index + 1).join('\n');
  lineNumbers.textContent = lineNumbersContent;
}

function syncScroll() {
  const lineHeight = htmlCode.scrollHeight / htmlCode.rows;
  lineNumbers.scrollTop = htmlCode.scrollTop;
  previewFrame.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, htmlCode.scrollTop * (previewFrame.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight / htmlCode.scrollHeight));
}


The project is an html5 code editor which allows to execute the code by pressing a button and delete it by pressing another button.

//Fucionar scrol para dos ventanas
htmlCode.addEventListener('input', updateLineNumbers);
htmlCode.addEventListener('scroll', syncScroll);

function updateLineNumbers() {
  const lines = htmlCode.value.split('\n').length;
  const lineNumbersContent = Array.from({ length: lines }, (_, index) => index + 1).join('\n');
  lineNumbers.textContent = lineNumbersContent;
}

function syncScroll() {
  lineNumbers.scrollTop = htmlCode.scrollTop;
}


// ... (código existente)

// Llamamos a updateEditor al cargar la página para mostrar el número 1 inicialmente
updateEditor();

// Sincronizar scroll para dos ventanas
editorContent.addEventListener('scroll', syncScroll);

function updateEditor() {
  updateLineNumbers();
  // Asegurar que el número 1 esté visible al inicio
  lineNumbers.scrollTop = 0;
  htmlCode.scrollTop = 0;
}

The project is an html5 code editor which allows to execute the code by pressing a button and delete it by pressing another button.
```

```css
.editor {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.editor-content {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  resize: none;
}

.line-numbers {
  height: 500px;
  counter-reset: line;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: pre;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  scroll-snap-stop: normal;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ocultar la barra de desplazamiento */
}

.html-code {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.html-code::before {
  content: counter(line);
  display: block;
  color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.editor-preview {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.editor-options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
}
The project is an html5 code editor which allows to execute the code by pressing a button and delete it by pressing another button.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Editor HTML5</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="editor">

    <div class="editor-content" id="editor-content">
      <div class="line-numbers" id="line-numbers"></div>
      <textarea id="html-code" class="html-code" placeholder="<!-- Escribe el código a continuación  --"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-preview">
      <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-options">
      <button id="run-btn">Ejecutar</button>
      <button id="reset-btn">Reiniciar</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your project intended to be in english? Is [es.so] intended to be in english? Translate to spanish or your question will be prosecuted and sentenced for closure. La interfaz de usuario en castellano te debe haber confundido y piensas que estás en el sitio en inglés, disculpa que la interfaz en castellano se parezca tanto al inglés, trataremos que esto no ocurra de nuevo. Mientras tanto, si no es mucho pedir, traduce tu pregunta al castellano o la comunidad votará para cerrar tu pregunta. No es discriminación, simplemente el idioma oficial de este sitio es castellano.